# Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime throws out-of-range error

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have to modify a column of my view, it's of type `nvarchar`, I need it as `datetime`.

[image]

This is how it was created on the view:

```
ISNULL(FORMAT(input, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'), '') MyDate
```

I'm trying to convert it to datetime:

```
CONVERT(datetime, ISNULL(FORMAT(input, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'), ''), 126) MyDate
```

But this throws an error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: `@input MyDate`?..

Comment: Is `@input` already a `DateTime`? If so do what @GSerg suggested.

Comment: If `@input` is a string, applying `FORMAT()` to it doesn't do what you think it does. Try `CONVERT(datetime, @input, 103)` or fix your source so you aren't using terrible date formats. Also you say `@input` is "on the view" but that makes no sense, you can't have a variable in a view. How is `IsDatetime` calculated? And why `nvarchar`? You need your date/time string to support emojis?

Comment: Your view contains the column mydate which is a string (obviously) but one that contains an empty value when the original column is null. What value do you propose to convert that to? And the format of 126 is just wrong - that format value tells convert what the format of your STRING is in order to convert it to datetime. That format is NOT 126. You can try 131 but I have my doubts. I suggest you change your view or select from the underlying table,

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=40a87aac532cc366803658696feaa0d5

Comment: Date format 126 expects a date in the form 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss' (more or less). Changing 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss' to 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss' (hyphens and "T" in place of slashes and space) will fix the second statement.  And as stated above, if @input is already a datetime, you probably don't need to do a conversion. Exception may be if you need to truncate fractional seconds.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. There's no variable involved, I edited the ask.

Comment: `input MyDate`?..

Comment: `''` is not a valid date, I suggest you remove the whole `ISNULL`. One assumes that if `FORMAT` is there then `input` is already a `datetime` in which case you should just select from the base table

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(your_column,10),101)
```